# В каких случаях правильно употреблять "на реку", а в каких "в реке"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Пойду на реку помоюсь. Помоюсь на реке (в  реке).*

Comment: Вы точно моетесь в/на реке?!

Answer (score 1):

Все ваши варианты правильные, есть только нюансы употребления.

*Пойду н**а** реку помоюсь.*
*Помоюсь на реке* — пойду н**а** реку и буду мыться на территории реки и прилегающей.
*Помоюсь в реке* — непосредственно мытьё будет происходить в реке.

Answer (score 1):

Вы про то, что "иду на (реку)", но "моюсь в (реке)"? Это нормально.

А если по поводу ***"мыться в/на"***, то мыться лучше дома или в бане. Но с грамматической точки зрения оба варианта возможны. Хотя я плохо представляю себе процесс подобного мытья. Если речь о том, что вы сидите **в реке** (в воде) и там прямо себя моете - ну что ж, значит "в реке".
А если река это просто удобное место, где есть вода, а мытье происходит на берегу - ну тогда и "мыться на реке" возможно, хотя повторюсь, несколько сомнительно по семантике.

Но у вас-то и ситуация другая.

"Пойду на реку" - абсолютно законное выражение. А "помоюсь" только задает цель вашего похода. **Пойду на реку помоюсь, постираюсь, позагораю, поплаваю, порыбачу** - все это допустимо, ограничения только на стилистику самого глагола ("постираюсь" - вариант народно-разговорный). Других проблем с использованием "пойду на реку" я не вижу.

Comment: Г-н behemothus, вроде как сам процесс мытья к грамматике не относится,а вы его расписали чрезвычайно подробно. Надо полагать, чтобы никто не мог придраться к длине ответа? Это тоже на букву Г, но немножко другое – гигиена.

Comment: @Niemand не вижу в вашем комментарии содержательных замечаний. Впрочем, даже в таком виде я в принципе не согласен с вами. Например, с утверждением, что я расписывал процесс мытья. Я объяснял семантику, насколько мне это удалось, это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Мыться, конечно, можно только *в реке* (а также в озере, в море, в бане, в ванной и т. д.) А идти - только *на реку* (на озеро, на пруд, на море). Честно говоря, непонятно, с чем связаны ваши трудности.

Comment: Если быть совсем точным, то непосредственно в ванне, не так ли?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/28928)

Comment: >> *Материал без указания ссылок может быть оспорен или даже удалён.* Господа модераторы, оспорьте! А оспорив, удалите. Но только когда удастся оспорить, не раньше.

Comment: @Aer дело не в ссылках. Я забраковал этот ответ, поскольку он формально не отвечает на заданный вопрос. Отвечающий "не заметил" примеров использования, а в них-то вся суть.

Comment: Зато ваш ответ, г-н @behemothus, прекрасно и неформально отвечает. **А если по поводу "мыться в/на", то мыться лучше дома или в бане.** Образцовый ответ на тему грамматики!